# Merge two select statements with appending clause

Tags: sql, abap

Hello I have two select statements that are executed right after each other. The programming language is ABAP. Is it possible to merge those two select statements in order to reduce the amount of select statements?

```
SELECT * FROM (me->db_table)
UP TO mynumber ROWS
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE mytable
WHERE x =  y
AND n =  m
ORDER BY (x).

SELECT * FROM (me->db_table)
UP TO mynumber ROWS
APPENDING CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE mytable
WHERE x  =  y
AND n =  m
ORDER BY (x).
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a realistic example that illustrates why you need two `SELECT` statements in the first place. The example you included simply shows the same statement twice.

Comment: yes it is the same statement twice at the moment and I would like to merge those two querys to one query (since the are similar but the seconde query is added to the first one). I don't think that I need two querys, thats the reason I would like to merge

Comment: @Tyzak So the issue is you just need 2 of every result from the query?

Comment: You don't need the 2nd select. You could append the content of the table again to the table. But the example is very obscure - Waht do you want do achieve?

Comment: Maybe it's just me but it doesn't seem entirely clear what you are trying to do. Could you perhaps illustrate it with the help of a data sample and the expected result based on that data sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any change to x or me->db_table between those two statements? If not, simply do

```
SELECT * FROM (me->db_table)
UP TO mynumber ROWS
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE mytable
WHERE x =  y
AND n =  m
ORDER BY (x).

append lines of mytable to mytable.
```

I'm not sure if the last statement issues a syntax error, if so, try

```
SELECT * FROM (me->db_table)
UP TO mynumber ROWS
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE tmp
WHERE x =  y
AND n =  m
ORDER BY (x).

append lines of tmp to mytable.
append lines of tmp to mytable.
```

where tmp should have the same type as mytable. The point is, that both selects are identical, therefore the result is, that you'll have the same data in mytable twice.